# How to get the PostgreSQL as a db file into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

**My Environment is::**

Windows 7,

Eclipse juno,

PostgreSQL 9.2,

PostgreSQL jdbc3 driver (jar files),
& Backup pf my database (`SampleDb.sql`)

[My DOUBT Image View](http://postimg.org/image/wwp8rwfhd/)

Is there any way to solve this?

I also need the Statements to connect the DataBase from the same Project..
something like [Statements](http://postimg.org/image/9i11hidhh/)

Answer (score 0):

can you at least stablish a connection to your progress db?

```
// load driver
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
//stablish connection
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user","fred");
props.setProperty("password","secret");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

If that work, then you simply do a :

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select * from FOO");
while(result.next()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i can connect this way to the database :-) but what happened is my eclipse juno is'nt making this postgresql 9.2 in my pop-up,to manually add a database into my project. check the Image View above once,it may explain u better ..